# entity framwork oracle : inserting more than 2000 characters into a VARCHAR2 (4000 CHAR) fail

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6, odp.net

We use .NET Entity Framework 6.0 and Oracle 12g.

When inserting more than 2000 characters into a VARCHAR2 (4000 CHAR) db column, we get an Oracle Error.

```
 ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column`
```

How can I resolve this problem please

Comment: Sounds a lot like a UTF-16/UCS-2 issue.  What's your database character set?

Answer (score 1):

In the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm) it's mentioned that the limit is

> Maximum size: 4000 bytes

But in real life it is **2000 for double byte chars**

To solve this issue you could use `CLOB` instead of `VARCHAR2`

Comment: Unfortunately the 4000 chars limit is still a problem for CLOB. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/CrazyJson/Citms.EntityFrameworkCore.Oracle/issues/14).

Answer (score 1):

This caused a bit of a headache for me today. To solve it without touching the DB I added the following to OnModelCreating().

`modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("VARCHAR2"));`

If required you can also do the following on an entity by entity basis, but for me all the strings are mapped to VARCHAR2 anyway so  I went with the former:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>().Property(x => x.SomeProperty).IsUnicode(false);
```